# Setting an Excel worksheet's custom page size (not the printable area) from Perl

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

Long story short, all I'm really attempting to do is print my reports on half sheets. I had Kinko's chop a pack of printer paper in half and my laser printer is perfectly happy to suck them in and print the reports properly, if the paper size of the Excel report is set to exactly 8.5" x 5.64".

That can be done easily in Excel, but it's the one and only adjustment, in my project, I wasn't able to automate with Perl using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm). The CPAN documentation states that you can pick from some of the default sizes normally available with Excel, but doesn't provide an option to specify your own paper size.

Even if you establish the custom size you need in Excel beforehand, making it available in future spreadsheets, as one of your selectable paper sizes, there doesn't seem to be an index, using [set_paper($index)](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#set_paper%28%24index%29), that would specify that newly established custom size.

Thank you in advance!

```
    #!/usr/local/gnu/bin/perl --
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

    my $repWB = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('../tmp/test.xls');
    my $repWS = $repWB->add_worksheet('AA');

    $repWS->set_paper(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since VBScript can do many of these things natively, maybe you could try embedding the necessary VBScript into your main Perl script using [Inline:WSC](http://search.cpan.org/~johnd/Inline-WSC-0.02/lib/Inline/WSC.pm).

You could determine the needed VBScript by recording an Excel macro of you setting the print size.  Then embed that code into your main Perl script.

Comment: Ooh, interesting. I'll give that a shot, let you know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of Spreadsheet::writeExcel.

As far as I know there isn't an option in Excel to set a custom paper size. This is usually set in the printer (correct me if I am wrong).

Excel can store printer information along with the workbook data so there may be a workaround.

Can you send me a single sheet workbook with data in cell A1 only and a copy with the custom page set and I'll take a look to see if it is possible.

P.S. The available option B5 (index 13) in landscape mode is fairly close: 8.27" x5.83". Or the undocumented "Organiser L" (index 129) which should be half Letter size: 8.5" x 5.5".

Comment: Found a thread which appears to have a VBScript workaround: http://www.vistax64.com/vb-script/241888-how-set-paper-size-vbs.html

Comment: I sent you the information you asked for to your jmcnamara@cpan.org last week. I didn't know for sure if you received it. Thank you!

Comment: Chad, I sent a reply (I'll send it again). Basically, there isn't any easy way to do this.

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate the attempt!